# Does tf.histogram_fixed_width() support back propagation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use the histogram of the output from a CNN to compute the loss. I am wondering whether `tf.histogram_fixed_width()` supports the gradient to flow back to its former layer. Only it works, I can add a loss layer after calculating the histogram.

Answer (score 2):

`tf.histogram_fixed_width()` does not support autogradient functionality since histogram is not a continuous differential function. You can look at the following example which returns gradient None.

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

value_range = [0.0, 5.0]
a = np.array([-1.0, 0.0, 1.5, 2.0, 5.0, 15])

x = K.variable(a)
hist = tf.histogram_fixed_width(x, value_range, nbins=5, dtype=tf.float32)
gradient = K.gradients(hist, x)

# output is [None]
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a solution:

As Stephen mentioned, a histogram isn't a continuous function (or even mostly continuous), so it's not differentiable. However, what you're probably looking for is actually a density estimate for the distribution of intensities. You can calculate one using kernel density estimation (KDE). It's similar to a histogram, except the intensity values are interpolated so a continuous change in intensity will correspond to a continuous change in the density estimate.

The easiest way to do this in Tensorflow currently is using Tensorflow Probability. There's an example in their original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10604.pdf) (see section 5.1):

```
f = lambda x: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal( loc=x, scale=1.))
n = x.shape[0].value
kde = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical( probs=[1 / n] * n),
components_distribution=f(x))
```

Note you'll have to install tensorflow_probability (pip works) and import tensorflow_probability as tfp and/or import tensorflow_probability.Distributions as tfd.

It's also possible to roll your own, although working out a way to do it without writing a custom op is a bit tricky. For the adventurous, a good place to start is this [paper](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse577/17au/notes/mattes.pdf) (see eq. 6; you only need the second term for a 1d histogram/distribution).

My (lightly tested) effort:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def cubicSplineFunction(arg):
    """ Applies the cubic spline basis function to the argument """
    absX = tf.math.abs(arg)
    sqrX = tf.math.square(arg)
    coef1 = (4.0 - 6.0*sqrX + 3.0*sqrX*absX) / 6.0              # |arg| < 1.0
    coef2 = (8.0 - 12.0*absX + 6.0*sqrX - sqrX*absX) / 6.0      # |arg| < 2.0
    lt1 = tf.cast(tf.where(absX <= 1,1,0),tf.float32)
    lt2 = tf.cast(tf.where(absX < 2,1,0),tf.float32) * (1-lt1)
    out = coef1 * lt1 + coef2 * lt2
    return out
    
def bincountWithWeights(h,bins,weights):
    """ Adds weights[i] into h[bins[i]] for all i"""
    return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(h,tf.reshape(tf.cast(bins,tf.int32),[-1,1]),weights)

def parzenDensityEstimate(x,histN):
    """ Returns a cubic spline interpolated probability density estimate for x """
    padding = 2
    minOb = tf.reduce_min(x)-1e-4; maxOb = tf.reduce_max(x)+1e-4; 
    delta = (maxOb-minOb) / (histN-2*padding)
    min = minOb / delta - padding
    max = maxOb / delta + padding
    xs = tf.range(minOb-2*delta,maxOb+2*delta,delta)
    h = tf.zeros_like(xs)
    xn = x/delta - min
    xb = tf.math.floor(xn,tf.int32)
    for offset in range(-2,3):
        splineArg = (xb+offset)-xn+0.5        # 0.5 is to find the distance from the bin centre
        v = cubicSplineFunction(splineArg)
        h = bincountWithWeights(h=h,bins=xb+offset,weights=v)
    h = h / tf.reduce_sum(h)
    return h,xs


density, bins = parzenDensityEstimate([0.,10.,10.,10.,20.],histN=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. There are two ways you can try: 1. After the output layer, add an extra layer to produce the histogram; 2. Use something like `tf.RegisterGradient` or `tf.custom_gradient` to define your own gradients for the operations.